# Code decipher using do-while loops

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have to decode a message where the program asks for inputs that are 1-7. 
1 represents “D”. 2 represents “W”. 3 represents “E”. 4 represents “L”. 5 represents “H”. 6 represents “O”. 7 represents “R”. So I tried using the do-while loops to scan the string I put together and then scan each letter at a time, adding the said letter to the deciphered string. Please help. Here is my code:

```
        System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers, after each number you put in, press enter. The numbers can only be from 1 - 7.");

    int numInputs = 0;
    String code = "", deciphered = "";
    int input = 0, charNumber = 1;

    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        input = in.nextInt();
        code+=input;
        numInputs++;
    }while(numInputs < 10);

    System.out.println("Your code is " + code);
    do{
        switch(code.charAt(charNumber)){
        case 1: deciphered+="D";
        break;
        case 2: deciphered+="W";
        break;
        case 3: deciphered+="E";
        break;
        case 4: deciphered+="L";
        break;
        case 5: deciphered+="H";
        break;
        case 6: deciphered+="O";
        break;
        case 7: deciphered+="R";
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Something went wrong! Try again with numbers only 1 - 7.");
        }
        charNumber++;
        numInputs++;
    }while(numInputs < 10);

    System.out.println("The output is: "+deciphered);
}
```

Comment: Please help with, what?  You haven't expressed a problem that needs help.

Comment: What is the questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your second do-while-loop (which should probably be a for-loop instead) is using `numInputs < 10` as its conditional. Since `numInputs` is already 10 because of the first do-while-loop, your second do-while-loop will only go through once. You don't use `charNumber` anywhere else, and it makes more sense to use here for the condition. Also, it would have to be set to 0 to start with, because `String`'s indices start at 0.
2. When you add the numbers to `code`, they are being converted into `char`s that correspond to that number, so 1 -> '1', 2 -> '2', ... This is going to cause your `switch` to fail every time. You have two options here: either use an array of `int`s to hold the code, or change the `case`s to check for `char`s instead of `int`s.
3. Not related to any of your problems, but you should close `in` at the end of the function. `in.close();`